# Coding a custom navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem once and having it reused in both UITableViewControllers and UIViewControllers?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitableview, subclass, viewcontroller, code-cleanup

I have successfully added a `rightBarButtonItem` to my `navigationBar`, but I would prefer to only have the code to do so show up once rather than once per type of `ViewController`. Here's my current setup:

```
                -->TVC
               |
NVC--->TVC--->TVC--->VC
```

So far I've subclassed `UITableViewController` and moved my code for adding the button into my subclass. All 3 of my `TableViewControllers` are set to that subclass and it works perfectly.

However now I need my lone `ViewController` to also show the button, but I don't know how to accomplish this without duplicating the code from my TVC subclass. Is subclassing the right answer or do I need a different approach?

Edits:

@CarlVeazey - Sure, I call it from the viewDidLoad function.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BETA" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(betaPressed)];
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the button? i.e. are you adding it to the navigation item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a pull-up refactor into a `UIViewController` category. If your project already has one, just add this code there, otherwise press cmd-N in Xcode to create a new file and choose "Objective-C Category" and enter `UIViewController` in the "Category On" field.

In the interface add this method declaration:

```
- (void)onfConfigureRightNavigationBarButton;
```

And in the implementation add this method implementation:

```
- (void)onfConfigureRightNavigationBarButton
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BETA" 
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                             target:self 
                                                                             action:@selector(betaPressed)];
}
```

Then in any `UIViewController` subclass you can import your category header and call this method. You may also wish to add to your category an empty implementation of `betaPressed:`.

BTW, ONF is the prefix I use for non-work coding so use whatever prefix already is in your project, or none at all if you're not concerned with category name collisions.

Comment: Wow, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! After doing like you said for my UIViewController subclass, I went into my UITableViewController subclass and imported the header and called the Category function from my viewDidLoad there as well. Now I have one place to manage my button code and it's used acrossed all of the screens I intended it to. I'd mark this as the answer if I had enough rep. Thanks a ton, sir!

Comment: Right on! Pretty sure you can mark accepted without having rep, you just can't upvote... could be wrong though. EDIT: looks like there might be a waiting period or something... well if you have time later it would be awesome to have it marked as the answer! Thanks!

Comment: Already solved my problem and still teaching me the ways of the Force. Thanks again! =)